# using registerHelper for onclick but function executes on page render

Tags: handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm using handlebars and I'm trying to pass in a function, but this function executes on page load instead of onclick, so trying to see what's wrong

So this is the js code

```
handlebars.registerHelper("randomOperation", () => {
      randomFile.functionCall()
})
```

Now on handlebar side, this is the code:

```
<a href="/newURL" target="_blank" onclick={{randomOperation}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use a [Handlebars Custom Helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#custom-helpers) as an `onclick` event handler. These two types of functions execute at very different times.

The Handlebars helper is executed when the template is rendered - ie., when the template function is turning a string of template into a string of HTML. The helper is called so as to affect the rendered output. For example, an `uppercase` helper might uppercase some string values that are passed to it in the template.

The `onclick` is executed in response to a click event on the element by the user. Handlebars has spit-out its HTML and that HTML has been parsed and added to the HTML document *before* it becomes a clickable.

Therefore, in order to add an `onclick` handler, you will need to define that function globally in your client-side JavaScript. It has nothing to do with Handlebars and is not affected by the templating language you are using to create your HTML.